# ASP MVC based site: IE8 requesting 'null' static resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've noticed in my ELMAH log a few times the following error:

The controller for path '/assets/css/null' was not found or does not implement IController.

There's only one place on the site which references this file: inside our _CSS.cshtml view.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">
```

How can this somehow turn the 'style.css' into 'null'? I've not actually seen the problem happening but our log file shows that it has, and the user agent string identifies the browser as IE8. I've refreshed the page that is shown as the HTTP_REFERER for this error but can't simulate it myself.

It's a bit mystifying!
Thanks